# what method is executed when I click a JCheckBox

Tags: java, swing

I have written a class that extends JCheckBox and am now looking to override the method that gets executed when the check box is clicked.  I have tried 'setSelected', and 'doClick', but neither do as I expect.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's an event-driven model; what you need to do is attach an [ItemListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html) to the checkbox.

See the Swing Tutorials: [How to use check boxes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#checkbox).

Your code might look something like this:

```
...
myCheckBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            // the checkbox was just selected
        } else {
            // the checkbox was just deselected
        }
    }
});
```